# How to refresh indexes in Laravel Scout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel to show a list of items from a database (SQL Server) that will be updated by another piece of software. So, with Laravel I only show items, without the insert, update or remove features.

I'm using Laravel Scout with TNTSearch (https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver) for searching in the list of items. The problem is, how can I refresh the index every time there is a change in the database table?

Comment: did you find answer for this?

Comment: one year later i don't remember how i did for resolve, but for sure i didn't utilized Laravel Scout

Comment: I have made a package that will refresh every model anywhere in your application using Scouts `scout:flush` and `scout:import` command

https://github.com/tarreislam/laravel-scout-refresh

Answer (score 2):

I have made a package that will refresh every model anywhere in your application using Scouts `scout:flush` and `scout:import` command

https://github.com/tarreislam/laravel-scout-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Check the indices you have,for example elasticsearch

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

health status index    uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   statuses GBNC5c4jQiqgNqBMEGJJJw   1   1          1            0      5.7kb          5.7kb
yellow open   users    Sndfs-KeQWeK6zv5p8BEpw   1   1         52            7     72.6kb         72.6kb
```

Delete the desired index

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/statuses'
```

Reimport the data

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Status"
```

Another shorcut for delete is

```
php artisan scout:flush "App\Status"
```